# change citation font with biblatex and custom bbx file

Tags: fonts, biblatex

I use the `chem-biochem.bbx` file from the `biblatex-chem`package, but it changes the font of the citation labels and the journal name to something i dont recognize, a font i have never seen in any biochemistry journal.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=chem-biochem,
    autocite=superscript,
    backend=biber,
    hyperref=true,
    url=false,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    maxnames=4]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Wald.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\autocite{Wald}
\lipsum[2]\autocite{Attwood}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This looks as follows:
[image]

However the `chem-biochem.bbx`is the only style I found after searching for a long time, I would really like to keep it. But this font is a dealbreaker. How can I change it to the standard `rm` font?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=chem-biochem,
    autocite=superscript,
    backend=biber,
    hyperref=true,
    url=false,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    maxnames=4]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]{\autocite{doody}}
\lipsum[2]\autocite{herrmann}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that solved it! I am however still wondering, where in the bbx this font got declared. It doesnt have any ```\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{}``` or similar code for ```default``` (which was my guess, since you used the non starred declare field command), and I dont find any ```\fontfamily{}```either.

Comment: the bbx loads other bbx and also biblatex.def and the definitions are from there.

Comment: I just realized that my problem was the italization. Writing numbers in italics produces these, for lack of a better word, fancy numbers. I cant seem to get rid of that font or shape. I tried loading different fonts a.e. ```usepackage[scaled]{helvet}``` but the emphasized and italic numbers are still the same style (the rest changes dramatically though). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry I have no real idea what you mean. The italic numbers are the standard roman family (cmr) italic, and loading helvet wouldn't change them, as helvet only changes the sans serif family.